# how to get a nested data from Concatenate values with same keys in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, string-concatenation

I have all_writing_test_name_data

```
all_writing_test_name_data=    
      [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "book_name": Math,
            "writing_test_description": "string",
            "subject_id": 1,
            "book_id": 2,
            "writing_test": "string"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "book_name": Math-1,
            "writing_test_description": "string-1",
            "subject_id": 1,
            "book_id": 2,
            "writing_test": "string-1"
          }
        ]
```

and I want to Concatenate all_writing_test_name_data like this

```
 [
  {
    "subject_id": 1,
    "writing_items": [
      {
            "id": 1,
            "book_name": Math,
            "writing_test_description": "string",
            "book_id": 2,
            "writing_test": "string"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "book_name": Math-1,
            "writing_test_description": "string-1",
            "book_id": 2,
            "writing_test": "string-1"
          }
    ]
  }
]
```

i have tried this but i think there is some lacking in the code for this i can't get the desire data

```
    x=all_writing_test_name_data
    

    # printing original list
    print("The original list is : " + str(x))
    
    import operator
    from functools import reduce
    all_keys = reduce(operator.or_, (d.keys() for d in x))

    bar = {key: [d.get(key) for d in x] for key in all_keys}

    print('bar',bar['writing_test']+bar['writing_test_description'])


    from collections import Counter
    result = Counter()
    for d in x:
        result[d['writing_test']] = d['writing_test']
        result[d['writing_test_description']] = d['writing_test_description']
    print(result)

    z=bar['writing_test']+bar['writing_test_description']

    print bar
```

but I can't get my desire data. how can i get the exact same data,what is the mistake

Comment: It looks like you are missing information in your writing_items list in the output. Is it your intention to ignore writing_test from id=1 and only include the writing_test from id=2 only?
What happens to "book_name": "Math-1" ??

Comment: i have edited the question for better understanding, please kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the input data by the `subject_id` property of each `dict`, then re-format that data into the value you want:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

groups = defaultdict(list)
for test in all_writing_test_name_data:
    subject_id = test.pop('subject_id')
    groups[subject_id].append(test)

result = [ { 'subject_id' : k, 'writing_items' : v } for k, v in groups.items() ]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "subject_id": 1,
        "writing_items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "book_name": "Math",
                "writing_test_description": "string",
                "book_id": 2,
                "writing_test": "string"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "book_name": "Math-1",
                "writing_test_description": "string-1",
                "book_id": 2,
                "writing_test": "string-1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Note that this will alter the value of `all_writing_test_name_data` (due to the `test.pop()`). If this is not desired, add

```py
test = test.copy()
```

prior to the `pop`.

Comment: subject_id = test.pop('subject_id')
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'pop'   i have just find this error

Comment: @trencherman don't accept an answer if it doesn't work... if you try to run the code twice on the same data you might see that error because the code modifies `all_writing_test_name_data`; see my note under the code for how to work around that using `copy`

Comment: @trencherman you can unaccept by clicking the arrow again...

Comment: woking fine noww. Thanks a lot Master